# How to shif a commit in the correct branch? I pushed it into the master instead into the correct feature branch

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I am not so into GIT and I have the following problem.

I created a new repository on BitBucket and I create a new feature branch named **feature/skeleton**.

[image]

Then i made the following mistake: I pushed on the wrong branche (I pushed my code into the **master** branche), as you can see here:

[image]

What can I do to shift (or something like this) this commit (having ID=b3542a8) into the correct **feature/skeleton** branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the `feature/skeleton` branch you might have left out the `--no-track` flag, so your branch was pointing to `origin/master`. Conceptually, you could do this:

1. Point your local branch to the proper upstream branch (likely `origin/feature/skeleton`), and then re-push it.
2. Change origin/master to go back to how it was before.

The commands to achieve this are (assuming your remote is origin):

```
# Get your local repo copy up to date
git fetch
# checkout your feature branch
git checkout feature/skeleton
# set the proper upstream
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/skeleton
# push out your branch to the proper remote branch
git push

# now we'll fix master by checking it out
git checkout master
# set master to the commit ID you want it to be on (maybe it's c6afa8f), if needed
git reset --hard c6afa8f
# replace the remote master
git push --force-with-lease
```

That's it!